# Saving files to application storage directory gives an I/O error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

In my tablet app I download files from the server and I try to save these files to my application storage directory. Then I get an error which says:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2038: File I/O Error.
```

It is occuring on this line:

```
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
```

Maybe some files are corrupted on the server but I can influence this. I tried to catch the error, but this isn't working. What do I do wrong?

**The complete code**

```
try {
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(_path);   

var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);

var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();           
_urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, _urlStream.bytesAvailable);

fileStream.writeBytes(fileData,0,fileData.length);

fileStream.close();
} catch(error:Error) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: have you tried to add IOErrorEvent to fileStream?

Comment: Yes, I tried this.. But if this error is thrown, so I don't think it will stop throwing errors when a listener? Or do you have experience with this?

Comment: The error you have displayed is not caused by missing a file but by missing the listener that should capture missing file errors. Add event listener and if file exist then no errors will appear, if file will not exist (or any other IO errors) then in your listener you will be able to deal with it.